# Locale based parameter values in Symfony2

Tags: php, facebook, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app, with multiple locale and every domain has his own domain name (means the locale is not prefixed or appended after the domain) like "shoes.com" and "schue.de".

To perform this, I'm using the `jms_i18n_routing` bundle, which takes care of setting the right locale.

My problems comes when I want to integrate for example, Facebook login with `hwi_ouath bundle,` where I have to set the "app id" and "app secret" in my config.yml, but the apps are also locale specific (as from now on in Facebook you can create only 1 redirect URL) so I should change the parameter values somewhere, but at container compilation time, I don't have access to the Request object, to check for the locale and later I can't change the parameter values.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Apparently you need to solve it some other way, since you cannot change parameters after a container was compiled (assuming it's a production immutable container).

Comment: And there is really no way getting the request object at compilation time?

Comment: I don't think so - it does not exist yet (since its building heavily relies on the container)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with factory service.

```
<service id="facebook.factory" class="Acme\Facebook\Factory">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
    <argument>%facebook_credentials%</argument>
</service>
<service id="facebook" class="Facebook"
         factory-service="facebook.factory" factory-method="create"/>

<!-- use "facebook" where you need it -->
```

And create factory, something like this:

```
namespace Acme\Facebook;

class Factory
{
    //...

    public function __construct($requestStack, $credentials)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->credentials = $credentials;
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $r = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        // throw if $r is null
        $c = $this->credentials[$r->getHost()];
        return new Facebook($c);
    }
}
```

Just keep in mind that `facebook` service will be created just once. Assuming hostname/locale does not change in single request, this should be ok. If it can change, inject factory itself and call `create` when you need it. Of course, in this case you could save already created `Facebook` objects for each locale and reuse them.

Unfortunatelly, you will have to redefine the services, as the bundle configures service with single set of parameters, which is not acceptable in your situation. So, bundle integration will probably not work out of the box, but you can still use all the classes it provides.

Comment: Yes, but it's not only facebook, I mean I have other things what I would like to change, but I found a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

At the end I used this solution, maybe someone needs something like this:

In the AppKernel I made a server variable with the current http host:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
   /**
    * @inheritdoc
    */
   public function __construct($environment, $debug)
   {
       parent::__construct($environment, $debug);
       if ($hostEnv = $this->getHostEnv()) {
           $_SERVER['SYMFONY__HOST'] = $hostEnv;
       }
   }
  ...
   private function getHostEnv()
   {
       if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
           return $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
       }

       return null;
   }
   public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
   {
       $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
       $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/parameters.php');
   }
}
```

With the `SYMFONY__%` server variable you can create automatically parameters.

Then `parameter.php`:

```
<?php

require_once('PlasticConfig.php');

if (!empty($container)) {
    $plasticConfig = new PlasticConfig($container);
    $container = $plasticConfig->load();
}
```

Then `PlasticConfig.php`:

```
<?php

use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class PlasticConfig {

    /**
     * @var Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface
     */
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function load()
    {
        /** 
         * this was defined in the constructor of AppKernel 
         * at console command there is no HTTP_HOST variable
         */
        if (!$this->container->hasParameter('host')) {
            return $this->container;
        }

        $host = $this->container->getParameter('host');
        //Magic can be done here, important is, that you return your container instance here

        return $this->container;
    }
}
```

In my parameters.yml I have some parameters, with the names host_de, host_en ... and I will iterate through all the parameters and if I find a match with the current host then I have the locale from the parameter name. After that I just need to set the facebook parameters also from the `parameters.yml`, where I have parameters like: `facebook.de.app_id: XY` and `facebook.en.app_id: ZS`.

Comment: Would you clear cache separately for each hostname? How are you going to pass hostname from command line?

Comment: No, cache is the same for every host, as everything looks the same, same features, just translated.

Answer (score 0):

**config.yml**

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.php } #add this import

hwi_ouath bundle:
    # put this in the right place
    app_id: %facebook.app_id%
    app_secret: %facebook.secret%
```

**parameters.php**

```
<?php

$lang = 'en';

if ('schue.de' === $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) {
    $lang = 'de';
} // elseif (...

$container->setParameter('facebook.app_id', $container->getParameter('facebook.'.$lang.'.app_id'));
$container->setParameter('facebook.secret', $container->getParameter('facebook.'.$lang.'.secret'));
```

Comment: At the end my solution also didn't worked, as with prod env, the container is dumped so it will be fast